# Does the Amazon App Store charge for updated apps?

Tags: amazon-appstore

We have a new Android phone to replace an older one, and we use Amazon App Store.

We logged in with the same account on the new phone, and some of the apps show "Install".  But other apps that we have purchased in the past show a price instead of "Install" -- they seem to have lost the fact that we already purchased these apps.

For example: Polyclock World Clock purchased as a Free App of the Day (April 2012).  This shows a price ($2.99) instead of "Install".  However, if we click the price, it changes to "Buy" and then attempting to purchase, it says "You already own PolyClock World Clock -- please find it in My Apps."  However we can't find it anywhere installed on the phone.

This doesn't quite match the other similar situations I already searched for:

- logging into Amazon AppStore with different credentials
- messing with the apk?

The inconsistent purchase behavior makes me think it's a bug... but my other guess was that the version of this app was so old that perhaps it thinks it needs to repurchase.

I couldn't find information on Amazon matching this situation, although I might have missed it.  There was a lot of information about transferring Kindle apps.

Thanks!

Comment: My experience with the Amazon App Store has been: If I've bought an app on an account, but it's still showing the price, it doesn't actually charge me a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Amazon does not charge again for apps you've already purchased.  You are misunderstanding the message that pops up.  When they say "Please find it in My Apps" they don't mean in your device's app drawer, they mean within the Appstore.  While you are still within the Amazon Appstore, do the following:

1. Open the side drawer (by sliding it out from left to right, tapping the Amazon logo on the upper-left corner, or simply pressing the menu button):
   [image]
2. Select the "My Apps" option which is under the "Library" section:
   [image]
3. Tap on the "Cloud" tab, and all of your previously purchased apps will be there, with an option to install on your new device:
   [image]

You may need to refresh the list if it doesn't show up.

Comment: Sorry, posting straight from the phone without any editing software.  I'll shrink those when I get home.

Comment: Images shrunk to a more manageable size.

Comment: thanks! we didn't know we had to refresh the list.  very helpful!

Comment: @Chahk: tips: you can add the letters s/m/h to the end of the imgur URL to resize uploaded images. [More details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post).